# <img> messes up container size and breaks layout

Tags: html, css

Can anyone tell me why this breaks when i put an image tag there? It doesn't break the layout when there's only text, but when i add an image to the equation it messes up the layout like a float would.

I've tried float fixes but it didn't work, and i have no idea how else to fix it.

http://samturrell.co.uk/liberty/

Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit:

So apparently the dyanamicpage.js script is setting the height to the wrong value when the page changes. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Where is _there_? You need to provide more details.

Comment: Sorry, the image i'm, referring to is the "google map" towards the bottom of the page.

Comment: So what is actually messed up?

Comment: Can you provide examples of how it messes up, you can edit your post.
Post code, screenshots or examples so we can see what you mean.

Comment: Without the image https://www.dropbox.com/s/6a4hddhj021ipxf/Screen%20Shot%202012-08-17%20at%2003.05.41.png with the image https://www.dropbox.com/s/81j3ioxo3kijj8y/Screen%20Shot%202012-08-17%20at%2003.04.35.png

Comment: the problem is with `javascript`. Post the code which determines the height for `div#page-wrap` cause that occurs only at Chrome (at least) but not in IE or FF. In FF the div has `style="height: 1078px;"`but in Chrome only `style="height: 823px;"`

Comment: Whether image size is unknown? If it isn't you have to set `width/height` for image explicitly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me that you have two options if you can't delete `dynamicpage.js`

1. you can explicitly set `width/height` to image if you know the dimensions for advance
2. if you don't know them then try to change first line of the dynamicpage.js from:
   `$(function() {` to:`window.addEventLinstener('load', function() {`
   and remove dangling `)` on the last one

this is because jQuery load event occurs before all images downloaded and for `<img>` does not have any `width/height` set to it browser does not know its height so it assumes `0px`

Comment: Changing it to that stops the script working completely. the thing is, the height works when you change page to the "staff" page, but the index page messes up for some reason

Comment: There is none. I think it's because basically that script along with another script causes the page not to load, just refresh the content, so onload wont fire

Comment: try to add handler via `addEventLinstener` method

Comment: But why would the original script work when navigating to the staff page, but not navigating to the index page? they both have images on them

Comment: I don't see exactly that image on the staff. It has images but those have wrappers which have `min-height` set and so on. Why you can't set `height` on your map image, e.g. `<img style="height:250px;">`

Comment: I suppose that works, i just find it odd how it doesn't recognise that in the height. Thanks! Also, out of interest, how fast does the page load when you open it? It seems slow to me, but may just be my connection

Comment: 11 seconds it took on my computer

Answer (score 1):

Just make the page-wrap height auto.

Comment: @Sam T , actually try not to set height to `div#page-wrap`

Comment: There's nothing in the CSS/HTML that specifies the height of that element. It only appears in the chrome element inspector

Comment: @Sam T , it appears either in FF firebug and chrome dev-tools but in FF height is set to 1078px; (on my 1920x1200 monitor) and in Chrome it is set to 823px; I suspect that height is set via JS

Answer (score 0):

Your height is explicitly set on the page-wrap div. this has nothing to do with the image.

Comment: There's nothing in the CSS/HTML that specifies that. It only appears in the chrome element inspector

Comment: That sort of thing doesn't really "magically appear". My guess would be that you have some js that's setting the height at some point.

Comment: That just occurred to me. I've figured out that the dynamicpage.js is somehow setting it